# Eliminating the duplicates from a specific column

Tags: python, bash, awk, gawk

Let say i have a file as below

```
MGW24:EXT-1:YES:OK
MGW24:SET-4:NO:OK
MGW24:SET-132:NO:OK
```

I want to check the column one and see if it repeats. In case if any string got repeats i want to eliminate the duplicates and print rest of the columns as it is. Please do remember the space between column1 and 2.

Expected Output:

```
MGW24:EXT-1:YES:OK
     :SET-4:NO:OK
     :SET-132:NO:OK
```

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. You have to make an attempt yourself, and if you can't get it working post what you tried and we'll help you learn from your mistakes.

Comment: Hint: Set a variable the first column. Then when you process the next line, compare its value to the variable. If it's the same, replace it with spaces, otherwise print the whole line.

Comment: Please take the Stack Overflow [tour] and read "[ask]" (and some of the related articles in the Help Center) to learn how to write a good question for Stack Overflow, and what kinds of questions are on- and off-topic here.  Then [edit] your question to ask a single, _specific_ question (narrowing it down to just _one_ programming language), including what you've tried so far in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: PS:  There _is_ no space between columns 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F: 'seen[$1]++{c=length($1); $0=sprintf("%*s%s", c, "", substr($0, c+1))} 1' f file

MGW24:EXT-1:YES:OK
     :SET-4:NO:OK
     :SET-132:NO:OK
```

- Reference: [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new to awk can you please explain me.

Comment: I added a reference to awk programming. `seen` is an associative array that has key as `$1`. `seen[$1]++` block executes when `$1` is already in `seen` i.e. duplicate. `printf` command prints number of spaces as the length of `$1`. `sub` strips `$1` from record and `1` just prints it.

Comment: It's always risky to do any kind of sub() using an input field as either the regexp or the replacement string as it'll produce bizarre effects given various contents of that field (e.g. any RE metacharacter in the regexp part, or any backreference like `&` in the replacement part). In this case you'd be safer with `substr($0,length($1)+1)` or `substr($0,index($0,FS))` or `sub(/^[^:]+:/,"")`. FWIW I'd write the script as `seen[$1]++{c=length($1); $0=sprintf("%*s%s",c,"",substr($0,c+1))}1` if that weren't feeding the vampires of course :-).

Comment: Yes good point that `sub` can be risky if it `$1` has regex meta characters and using `substr` is much safer.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase: I think we can be little lenient with first time askers though completely agree that OP should show some effort in question. On a positive note it appears from comment that OP wants to learn awk.

Comment: @suren: Did this answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F":" -v OFS=":" '$1 in a{$1=a[$1]} !($1 in a){while(length(t) < length($1)) t=t" "; a[$1]=t} 1' file
```

Breakdown

```
$1 in a{$1=a[$1]} # if repeated set space to $1
!($1 in a){
 while(length(t) < length($1)) t=t" "; #create replacement text
 a[$1]=t #set it to array a
}
1 #print
```

Output

```
MGW24:EXT-1:YES:OK
     :SET-4:NO:OK
     :SET-132:NO:OK
```

Comment: `while(length(t) < length($1)) t=t; a[$1]=t" "` can be written as just `a[$1]=sprintf("%*s",length($1),"")`.